# Undefined references when building OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, fedora

I need to build my own OpenSSL binary because the package supplied with Fedora-18 does not have elliptic curve cryptography. I execute these commands:

```
./config --prefix=/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl --openssldir=/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl/openssl -fPIC zlib no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5
make depend
make
```

But I have linking errors:

```
../libcrypto.a(x86_64cpuid.o): In function `OPENSSL_cleanse':
(.text+0x1a0): multiple definition of `OPENSSL_cleanse'
../libcrypto.a(mem_clr.o):mem_clr.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
../libcrypto.a(cmll-x86_64.o): In function `Camellia_cbc_encrypt':
(.text+0x1f00): multiple definition of `Camellia_cbc_encrypt'
../libcrypto.a(cmll_cbc.o):cmll_cbc.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o): In function `AES_encrypt':
(.text+0x460): multiple definition of `AES_encrypt'
../libcrypto.a(aes_core.o):aes_core.c:(.text+0x62a): first defined here
../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o): In function `AES_decrypt':
(.text+0x9f0): multiple definition of `AES_decrypt'
../libcrypto.a(aes_core.o):aes_core.c:(.text+0xad0): first defined here
../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o): In function `private_AES_set_encrypt_key':
(.text+0xab0): multiple definition of `private_AES_set_encrypt_key'
../libcrypto.a(aes_core.o):aes_core.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o): In function `private_AES_set_decrypt_key':
(.text+0xd80): multiple definition of `private_AES_set_decrypt_key'
../libcrypto.a(aes_core.o):aes_core.c:(.text+0x403): first defined here
../libcrypto.a(aes-x86_64.o): In function `AES_cbc_encrypt':
(.text+0xfa0): multiple definition of `AES_cbc_encrypt'
../libcrypto.a(aes_cbc.o):aes_cbc.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

Comment: Why make depend? Just try make and make install.

Comment: `./config` prints that I need to issue `make depend`

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @Maxim - what else are you doing? You should not have these problems out of the box when building the library. I feel like you're not telling us everything.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem compiling OpenSSL 1.0.1e on SLES 11 Linux.
On another web site I found the hint to issue a "make clean" before calling make.

In my case, the *unsucessful* first attempt was:

Logged on as a normal user (not root):

```
. ./config
make
```

This failed with the same errors you mentioned in your question.

The *successful* attempt was:

```
su
make clean
./config zlib
make
make install
```

Comment: that worked for me, thanks. I also used `./config --prefix=$HOME enable-ec enable-ecdh enable-ecdsa zlib` but I'm not sure if those were all necessary.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me as well; RHEL 5.10. I used `./config --prefix=$HOME/usr_local --openssldir=$HOME/usr_local/openssl zlib`.

Comment: `make clean` did the trick for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> ./config --prefix=/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl --openssldir=/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl/openssl -fPIC zlib no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5
> make depend
> make
> ```

For `-fPIC`, you use `shared`.

There's no need for `--prefix` because it will use `--openssldir`. So the configuration invocation would be similar to:

```
./config shared zlib no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5 no-ssl2 no-ssl3 \
    enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 --openssldir=/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl/openssl
```

Some notes on the line:

- `enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128` is a speed-up for 64-bit platforms where GCC offers a 128-bit integer.
- Usually, you want `no-comp` because compression [can leak information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME)
- Because compression leaks information, you usually don't want `zlib`
- `no-ssl2` completely removes SSLv2 because its insecure
- `no-ssl3` completely removes SSLv3 because its insecure

`--openssldir=/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl/openssl` means:

- binaries will be in `/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl/openssl/bin`
- libraries will be in `/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl/openssl/lib`
- headers will be in `/home/USERNAME/bin/ssl/openssl/include`

Then, you only need to run the following. There's no need for `make depend`.

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

---

*If* you need to clean an existing configuration and then reconfigure, perform the following:

```
make clean && make dclean
```

`make dclean` is the key to re-configuring.

---

Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.